# Node.js + SQL - is Insert query faster than Select?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, foreach, async-await

I have a problem with SQL in node.js.

I have an array 'data' which contains some data returned from the async function and I want to put it into MySQL database if there's no result with the same data. There are some duplicated objects in array but I want to put just one into database.

*Function example:*

```
async function data_name(param){
    var data = [];
    data.push({
    name: param,
    sname: 'sname',
    url: 'url',
    report: 'report'
    });
    return data;
}
```

Then I run following code:

```
var data = await data_name('name');
data.forEach(item=>{
    var chk = "SELECT * FROM `?` WHERE `name` = ? AND `sname` = ?;";
    con.query(chk, [tablename, item.name, item.sname], function(er,items){
    if(er) throw er;
    if(items.length < 1){
        var insert = "INSERT INTO `?` (name, sname, url, report) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        con.query(insert, [tablename, item.name, item.sname, item.url, item.report], function(erg,added){
            if(erg) throw erg;
            console.log('Item added: ' + item.name);
        });
    }
    else{
        if(items[0].report != item.report){
            var upd = "UPDATE `?` SET report = ? WHERE id = ?";
            con.query(upd, [tablename, item.report, items[0].id], function(ere,edited){
                if(ere) throw ere;
                console.log('Item updated: ' +items[0].name);
                });
            }
        }
//broken code below
    var adc = "SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `link` = ?;";
    con.query(adc, item.url, function(erc, results){    
        //tried also with: results[0] === undefined || results[0] === null
        var test = item.url + ' ' + results.length;
        console.log(test);
        if(results.length < 1){
            var add_c = "INSERT INTO `links` (link_name, link_url) VALUES (?,?)";
            con.query(add_c, [item.name, item.url], function(era, a_link){
                if(era) throw era;
            });
        }
        else{console.log('Record exists');}
    });
    });
});
```

The first SQL works great: it inserts all records to database, there are no duplicates and it updates values if it is required.

Second SQL (mentioned by a comment in code that I put before) doesn't work properly if the database is empty. It duplicates records in database (after running it database has 470 records while every record is duplicated about 8 times).

test variable prints for eg:

- https://google.com 0
- https://google.com 0
- https://facebook.com 0
- https://facebook.com 0
- https://google.com 1
- https://facebook.com 0
- https://google.com 0

The problem exists only if a database is empty (if I run the code second time, the second SQL doesn't insert records new records and print in console 'Record exists'

Any ideas what can be reason of that?

Comment: At first time, your table has 0 records thus `result.length` < 1 holds `true` causing the insert query to run and insert data into the table. In another call to the function `result.length` < 1 holds `false`. Thus `else` statement is executed.

Comment: @beingsrv I want to put records into the table if there is no records, but I don't want to have duplicates of them.

If data[0] has a link to https://google.com and has inserted it into database, data[1] should return result.length = 1 and print in console 'Record exists'

Comment: I think due to async nature of node your getting odd result.
I would suggest use Promises to run the query to make operation 1 and 2 synchronous,
dataFetch().then( results => { operation1().then(results => {
    //do something here for operation2
}).catch(err)

Comment: @beingsrv thanks ;) I solved problem by deleting duplicates from an array with: `data = data.filter((thing, index, self) => 
       index === self.findIndex((t) => (
        t.name === thing.name && t.sname === thing.sname
       ))
      )`